# A fantasy short fiction by Asimov about a murder mystery writer whose sleuth comes to life

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

I read that story (possibly shortish novelette rather than technically "short story") at least 40 years ago.

A writer got rather successful with a series of murder mysteries with the same sleuth, a very effective but also extremely pretentious, even odious, character. To the former's dismay, his character "comes out of the page" and appears in "real life". He turns the writer's life into a nightmare. IIRC, the sleuth claims that all the stories are murder mysteries he actually solved and that the writer just wrote what he told him. Writing a story where his sleuth dies would kill his career. But he has a better idea. He writes a story where his sleuth is married to an extremely jealous wife. The latter reproves of her husband escaping from the books to the "real world" and "comes out of the page" herself to bring him home. The writer can now keep writing, but always keeps a story with the wife ready to be published to keep his character at bay.

Comment: I think you mean "disapproves" rather than "reproves"?

Comment: Yes, "disapproves" seems better. Sorry, not my first language...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is ["Author! Author!"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62432) by Isaac Asimov. It was written in 1943, but only published in 1964 (in the anthology "The Unknown Five"). It was also published in "The Early Asimov" (1972) and "The Asimov Chronicles" (1989).

Here's the plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Author!_Author!_(short_story)):

> Graham Dorn, a successful mystery writer, finds to his dismay that his most famous literary creation, a suave detective named Reginald de Meister, has become real. He usurps Dorn's life and even attempts to steal his fiancee. Graham counters by rewriting his current manuscript so that De Meister is married to the flashing-eyed, svelte, jealous Sancha Rodriguez, who promptly appears and accuses De Meister of two-timing her. The two characters disappear back into the world of fiction and Graham's life becomes his own again.

Comment: That was fast ! The synopsis you gave corresponds exactly to my memories but for one detail. I would not call this Reginald de Meister "suave". Viscous, squishy, repugnant would be my choice epithets. LOL

Comment: It's impressive how well you remembered the plot after 40 years.

Comment: Asimov stories often register very well in my mind. I feel a lot of connection with him. The only thing is, with increasing age, I forget names, of books, of characters, etc. But plots, yes, these I remember.

Comment: Ah, I was going to say that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_at_the_ABA has the protagonist interact with Asimov, but not in an antagonistic fashion. Rather, Asimov is at the convention as a character.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I just looked at the link you provided. No, the mixing of "real" and "fictional" was at a deeper degree, "just fiction" and "fiction inside the fiction" nor "really real world" and "fiction"... though the fictional characters in *Murder at the ABA* are writers so they might have interacted with their creations too.. My mind wobbles... Of course the "real" characters are not really real either.